# Doctrine query with relationships and count

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to do a complex query in Doctrine but had no luck so far.

I had an Entity called Category.

Category has reports (1 to many)
Category has subcategories (1 to many self referencing)

```
class Category extends
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Expose
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @Expose
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=".....\Category", mappedBy="parentCategory", cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @MaxDepth(1)
 *
 * @Expose
 *
 **/
private $subcategories;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="....\Category", inversedBy="subcategories", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idparent", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Expose
 */
private $parentCategory;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="....\Report", mappedBy="category")
 */
private $reports;
```

I use these entities in a rest API set up in symfony with FosRestBundle and HATEOASBundle.

So my objective is to return the following:

All parent categories (categories with idparent=null, meaning they are roots) with total_count reports and total_sum_reports of their subcategpories, with their subcategories with total_count reports and total_sum_reports.

Something like that:

```
name: parentCategory1
total_reports: 20
total_amount 100
subcategories: [
    [name: child 1, total_reports: 15, total_amount 80],
    [name: child 2, total_reports: 5, total_amount 20],
]
```

Unfortunately haven't figured this out.
How to take all info in need into a single json object?
Is it possible with Doctrine take all this into a big object or need to create this manually?

Comment: what "total_amount" is?

Comment: total amount is the SUM of report.amount and total_reports is the count of report

Comment: what does it means the "sum" of report and how this sum could differ from count of reports?

Comment: a category has reports and every report has an amount,

   total_report is how many reports a category has,
   total_amount is the sum of amount of these reports a category has